# type classes in Scala - a minimal self-contained example

Tags: scala

I looked at examples for type class scenarios and how to imitate this Haskell-ish concept in scala, e.g. at http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html. I think they are all too much involved and narrative-laden than they could be. Can you provide an authoritative *minimal* example for polymorphism using type classes rather than inheritance and mixins?

Thanks!

Comment: As written this question is 'asking for a resource'.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. It is asking for a minimal code example

Comment: I don't think "minimal" is at all well defined here, but comparing `Ordered` and `Ordering` in the standard library is a good place to start.

Comment: @matt Which is still asking for a code example (as opposed to why/how some code [doesn't] work, eg.); hence an off-site resource. A better question - or rather, one that wouldn't get my close vote - might be to show one typeclass['ish] implementation, for example, and ask a specific question about that.

Comment: Guys if you observe the answer below, you will see the petty comments are rather irrelevant. Tip: try to sympathize with the OP's intent, rather than obsess in aspergerish interpretation for that or other word... human communication is not like compiling a program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// type class
trait Show[A] { def show(x: A): String }

// usage
def greet[A](x: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = s"Hello ${sh.show(x)}"

// example instance
implicit object ShowDouble extends Show[Double] {
  def show(x: Double) = f"$x%1.3f" // format with three digits
}

greet(math.Pi)  // "Hello 3.142"
```

Comment: Coolness! Any intuition to why it's called a "type class"?

Comment: The concept along with the name were introduced in the 1988 paper "How to make _ad-hoc_ polymorphism less _ad hoc_" by Philip Wadler and Stephen Blott. Although they don't give an explanation for the name, the following example is illustrative: "a type `a` belongs to class `Num` if there are functions named `(+)`, `(*)` , and `negate`, of the appropriate types, defined on it." That is, the type class is a class (collection) of functions parametrised by a type.

Comment: Thanks, and I'd also call it to myself "implicit class membership", even though the scala way makes the membership quite explicit (`extends Show`...)

Comment: After not thinking about this for years and just accepting the name, I suddenly had the revelation that it's actually quite intuitive: type classes group types just like classes group values.